# get android element Id in Activity

Tags: android, android-edittext

How can I get element Id in android

```
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/etCustomerNo"
```

I need access to id of editText in my activity (for example get "etCustomerNo" as a String).
Thank you.

I need to know id of all editText on layout

```
for (int i = 0; i < rl.getChildCount(); i++) {
    if (rl.getChildAt(i) instanceof EditText) {
        String id = String.valueOf(rl.getChildAt(i).getId());
    }
}
```

`getId()` returns an `int` value instead of `"etCustomerNo"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    String s = getResources().getResourceEntryName(et.getId());
```

Et is your EditText object.
s is your id name.

Comment: I can get my edittext, but i can't retrieve id that I set in layout. I nedd to get etCustomerNo in android:id="@id/etCustomerNo"

Comment: Yeah, Use this code ,you can get the id name(the name contains your packageName,you can spilt it,get the accurate id name).  The result like this  'com.xxx.xxx:id/etCustomerNo'

Comment: There's a few helpful methods in this class that provide various levels of detail for the `id`: `getResourceEntryName()`, `getResourceName()`, `getResourcePackageName()` and `getResourceTypeName()`.

Comment: @PPartisan Yeah you are right, I update the answer，Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

by looking at `View`'s source code inside `toString()` method, we can see how you can get the `id` name as string:

```
    final int id = getId();
    if (id != NO_ID) {
        out.append(" #");
        out.append(Integer.toHexString(id));
        final Resources r = mResources;
        if (Resources.resourceHasPackage(id) && r != null) {
            try {
                String pkgname;
                switch (id&0xff000000) {
                    case 0x7f000000:
                        pkgname="app";
                        break;
                    case 0x01000000:
                        pkgname="android";
                        break;
                    default:
                        pkgname = r.getResourcePackageName(id);
                        break;
                }
                String typename = r.getResourceTypeName(id);
                String entryname = r.getResourceEntryName(id);
                out.append(" ");
                out.append(pkgname);
                out.append(":");
                out.append(typename);
                out.append("/");
                out.append(entryname);
            } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

the `entryname` string is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

```
EditText et=(EditText)FindViewById(R.id.etCustomerNo);
```

Comment: I want to get all id of EditText on layout.

Comment: This answer is not answering question. Read question before posting an asnwer Zeeshan.

Comment: You need to go through edits of his question. Then you will get it. Thanks for telling me.

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir then you might update your answer to keep it up.

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText edittext = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.etCustomerNo);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the `editText`, then try calling `getId()`. If you need to do anything further you'd like need to put together a `switch` statement formed of the various options:

```
private String getIdAsString(EditText editText) {

    String value = null;
    int id = editText.getId();

    switch (id) {

        case R.id.etCustomerNo:
            value = "etCustomerNo";
            break;
        case R.id.edit_text_two:
            value = "edit_text_two";
            break;

    }
    return value;
}
```